# Is there a way to assign a symbology automatically based on the file name in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, symbology, style

In QGIS is it possible that when I create a shapefile and give it a file name e.g. *Site*, that I can assign symbology to that automatically?

I have a set symbol for *Site* and many other features but would love it if I could auto assign the symbology based on the file name.

I know this is possible in ArcMap but am trying to find out whether this can be done in QGIS.

[image: What I mean in the context of ArcMap]

Comment: How is this done in ArcMap? I'm trying to figure out what this question means...

Comment: Please see the edit above, which describes it in the context of ArcMap.

Comment: @AGW94 - Perhaps not natively as you can assign default symbology to features when any layer is loaded (`Project > Project Properties > Default styles`) but you could create a python function which whenever a layer was saved using the `Save As...` option, it would automatically apply the style based on its name. I'm assuming these styles are saved as .qml files (e.g. _Site.qml_)?

Comment: @Joseph, thanks for the comment. Yes that would be exactly what I am looking for. I have many .qml files saved in my style manager, but would love the automatic assignment when I use the Save As... option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a script which reads all *.qml* style files in a given directory and stores them in a dictionary. We can create a function connected to the [layerSavedAs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a53893d6cae30151f63040bdec854e235) signal. When saving a layer via the `Save As...` option, the layer added to the map canvas can have a style loaded if both names match. The script can be used in the **Python Console**:

```
import glob, os

list_of_style_names = {}
stylePath = 'F:/QGIS Shared/Carterwood Styles'
for style in glob.glob(stylePath + '/*.qml'):
    styleName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(style))[0]
    list_of_style_names[styleName] = style

def applyStyle():
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    if layer.name() in list_of_style_names:
        layer.loadNamedStyle(list_of_style_names[layer.name()])

iface.layerSavedAs.connect(applyStyle)
```

When finished, you could use the following to disconnect the signal and delete the function:

```
iface.layerSavedAs.disconnect(applyStyle)
del applyStyle
```

Comment: After playing around with this I cannot seem to get it to work, I have defined the style path. Do I need to do anything else? Apologies as my python and coding in general is poor.

Comment: @AGW94 - No need to apologise! How did you define your style path exactly?

Comment: stylePath = 'F:\QGIS Shared\Carterwood Styles'

Comment: @AGW94 - Try using  `stylePath = 'F:/QGIS Shared/Carterwood Styles/'` or `stylePath = r'F:\QGIS Shared\Carterwood Styles\'` :)

Comment: Still can't seem to get it working with both of them

Comment: I now have it working! I was missing the * before the .qml. I must have deleted it somehow. What exactly does the * do?

Comment: @AGW94 - It acts like a wildcard so it will read all files which end in `.qml`. If you use `/*style.qml`, it will only read those files which have "style" at the end of the file name and also end with the ".qml" extension.

Answer (score 2):

Joseph's method is amazing. An alternative that is less technical and automatic is to have a set of .qml style files that you cut and paste into the same folder as your shapefiles. If a .qml file has the same name as a shapefile and is in the same folder Qgis will use it to style the shapefile.